# Срабатывает конструктор для initializer_list, а надо для int

Tags: c++, классы, конструктор

У меня есть класс, содержащий в том числе 2 конструктора:

```
#include <initializer_list>
#include <iostream>

struct A {
  A(int) { std::cout << "1"; }
  A(std::initializer_list<int>) { std::cout << "2"; }
};

int main() {
  A a1{1};
  A a2{1, 2};
}
```

Как сделать так, чтобы оба конструктора поддерживались, но объявление `a1` вызывало первый конструктор, а `a2` — второй?

Объявления должны остаться такими же простыми, а вот конструкторы можно менять.

Comment: `A a1(1);` так?

Comment: @timur так нормально вызывает, а можно вызвать первый конструктор с синтаксисом `{1}`?

Comment: У плюсистов это называется пук. Не используйте `std::initializer_list<int>`. Попробуйте просто `std::list<int>`.

Comment: @AlexGlebe что за пук? Если поставить просто лист, то второе объявление не работает

Comment: A a2(std::list<int>{1,2});

Comment: @AlexGlebe не, можно усложнять конструкторы, но объявления должны остаться простыми для пользователей

Comment: Ну тогда просто `A a2{{1, 2}};`. Так проще ?

Comment: @AlexGlebe проще, но мне надо именно `A a1{1};A a2{1, 2};`

Comment: Это очень странно, что есть такая необходимость. Это как бы нарушает логику, ведь одно число - это тоже список, а вы используете списковую инициализацию =)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

вызови этот констрактор напрямую

```
A a1(1);
```

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/111474/discussion-on-answer-by-ddd----initializer-list--).

Answer (score 4):

Если бы знать зачем вам это... Вместо `std::initializer_list` можно передать какую то другую последовательность(например `std::vector`), а можно, например, так:

```
A(std::initializer_list<int> a) 
{
    if (a.size() == 1)
        A(*a.begin());
    else
        std::cout << "2";
}
```

Comment: Если ставить вектор, то второе объявление не работает. С ифом работает (логика, а не этот код), но это медленней будет изза лишнего сравнения

Comment: С вектором нужны только дополнительные скобки:  `A a2{ {1, 2 } };`  А из за одного условия насколько замедлится конструирование объекта, даже смешно об этом говорить.   А вам нужно решение или вам нужно, чтобы вам ответили, а вы забраковали,?  Я же с самого начала сказал : "Если бы знать зачем вам это..."

Comment: Так если 1 раз вызвать то мало замедлится, а если мне массив из тысяч элементов таких надо? Уже будет глючить жостко

Comment: Нет, вы не будете тысяч раз вызывать конструктор таким способом. Второе: ваше копирование  займет не меньше времени. Третье: 1000 раз выполнить проверку размера, тоже  не так уж дорого...

Comment: @JIOX, сравнения практически ничего не стоят, фанатичные вы оптимизаторы =)